# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' - Optional chaining not removing error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Trying to implement a custom formcontrol. I have strict mode set to `true` and do not want to remove it. Implementing the control value accessor functions all work with optional chaining, except `setDisabledState`. Even doing an implicit check for value being possibly `undefined` does not fix the issue.

Relevant code:

```
@ViewChild(FormControlDirective, {static: true}) formControlDirective!: FormControlDirective;
@Input() formControl!: FormControl | AbstractControl;

@Input()
formControlName!: string;
get control(): FormControl {
  return (this.formControl || this.controlContainer?.control?.get(this.formControlName)) as FormControl;
}

constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

// .... more code

// ISSUE BELOW!!!
setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  if (this.formControlDirective && this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor) {
    this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.setDisabledState(isDisabled);
  }
}
```

Error being:

> `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`

I reproduced the issue in this **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vdpdz4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)** Note, disabling strict mode resolves the issue and code works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setDisabledState` is an optional property in the `ControlValueAccessor` interface:
https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Therefore, it might not be a function.

You can add optional chaining to the method call too, which should fix your error:

```
this.formControlDirective?.valueAccessor?.setDisabledState?.(isDisabled);
```

Comment: Oh silly me, thanks! Was too focused on `formControlDirective.valueAccessor`... instead of actually focusing on the `setDisabledState`.... tunnel vision :P

Comment: No problem - easy mistake, since the other function properties are not optional :)